# How to read an account state without needing Phantom wallet provider?

Tags: anchor, account, phantom, anchor-client, walletprovider

I create an instance of a Program in the following way and try to read accounts from the program instance.

```
const network = clusterApiUrl('devnet');
const connection = new Connection(network, "processed");
const provider = return new AnchorProvider(
    connection, window.solana, { preflightCommitment: "processed" },
);
const program = new Program<any>(idl, programID, provider)
```

**Problem:** If a user doesn't have Phantom wallet installed this would fail with the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading ‘publicKey’)
```

**Question:** How can I properly instantiate a Program to read accounts when a user doesn't have Phantom installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround. If the `solana` object is not found in `window`, passing a random public key solves the problem.

```
const wallet = window.solana ?? Keypair.generate();
return new AnchorProvider(
    connection, wallet, { preflightCommitment: "processed" },
);
```